# MariaDb - NamedQuery to filter records based on a column contains comma-separated values

Tags: spring-boot, mariadb, named-query

I have a Spring boot application that connects to a MariaDB to fetch records. In my MariaDb table, I have a column called `"tags"` and this column consists of comma-separated values something like `"summer,vacation,sea,sun,beach,travel"`.

There is a search form at the frontend. I want to create a `NamedQuery` to filter the search results.

I have something like this for the "tags" part:

```
" AND m.tags LIKE CONCAT('%', :tags, '%')"
```

This is working fine if the user input contains only one word like `"summer"` or `"vacation"`. It works with multiple words as well but only if you write those words exactly as they appear in the tags column, like `"summer,vacation"`.

The problem occurs when the user types something like: `"vacation summer"`. Since these values are not in order as they persisted in the database, the result becomes an empty list. I receive input value as a list of Strings in the backend.

How can I modify my existing NamedQuery to work with all possible inputs?

Comment: Recommend normalizing your data by putting tags into a separate table `tag (tag, id)` where `id` is the primary key of `m`. Then queries becomes `select group_concat(tag.tag),m.* from m join tag using id where tag.tag in (?)`

Comment: I agree with @danblack that you should normalize your data, but if it absolutely has to be this way, why not use regex?